# C++ code terminates by Segmentation Fault?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main() {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */  
    int num, qr, maxSize = 0;
    cin >> num >> qr;
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        int size;
        cin >> size;
        if (size > maxSize)
        {
            maxSize = size;
        }
    }
    int arr[num][maxSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        int s;
        cin >> s;
        for (int j = 0; j < s; j++)
        {
            int elem;
            cin >> elem;
            arr[i][j] = elem;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < qr; i++)
    {
        int a,b;
        cin >> a >> b;
        cout << arr[a][b];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code terminates giving Segmentation Fault Error. I am new to the world of C++ and I don't have any idea of this error message. Any help would mean a lot to me.

Comment: If `size` is less than `maxSize`,`maxSize` will remain **0**. The size of 2d array will have 0 as maxSize so It would create segmentation fault error.

Comment: please add the error log to the question

Comment: If `s` is larger than `maxSize` you'll write outside the matrix. What values are you entering? Maybe, try adding a user firendly message before each `cin >> ...` so to remind the user that we need the size here, the element there, and so on. You might be entering an element where you need to enter a size, otherwise.

Comment: `int arr[num][maxSize];` is not standard C++.

Comment: Obviously there are inputs that can cause out-of-bounds access. Please show us input, expected and actual output.

Comment: This would be a good time to learn how to use your debugger.  Once you know how to effectively use your debugger, you'll save tons of time down the road.